# Rspec doesn't fail this trivial code, even though it should

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

Controller:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  def create
  end
end
```

Controller spec:

```
describe FooController
  it "does bar" do
    Foo.should_receive(:new).with("text" => "Lorem ipsum")
    post :create, foo: { "text" => "Lorem ipsum" }
  end
end
```

When I run this, rspec says that it's a success. However, `Foo.new` is never called in the `create` method. If I change the `Lorem ipsum` in the `post` function call to something else, however, it fails. I would expect this to fail, and succeed if I added `Foo.new(params[:foo])` to the body of the `create` method. Why is this not the case?

Comment: Can you create a derived `Foo#new` that does something like `puts "HI!"` and calls `super`, then look at your test log to make sure that it is actually getting called?

Comment: Fails fine for me... you sure you're looking at the right controller code?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are missing a "do" on the describe block.  Try:

```
describe FooController do
  it "does bar" do
    Foo.should_receive(:new).with("text" => "Lorem ipsum")
    post :create, foo: { "text" => "Lorem ipsum" }
  end
end
```